# Плавная прокрутка страницы

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать плавную прокрутку страницы?

Comment: [Вот ещё](http://www.prostosem.in.ua/article/plavnaya_prokrutka_stranicyi_k_yakoryu_jquery) неплохое решение для плавной прокрутки

Answer (score 2):

Почему то как всегда, когда задаешь вопрос, сразу же находишь ответ.
Ответ:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-библиотека.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">  
         $(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e){
      var anchor = $(this);
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
         scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 1000);
      e.preventDefault();
   });
   return false;
});
</script>
```

В ссылке id="top" или любой другой.

Comment: Потому что в голове непонятная каша, которую как-то "по-понятному" распознает мозг. А вот когда нужно донести другим участникам свой вопрос, то вы его приводите в общий, понятный всем, вид. Поэтому сначала для себя сформулируйте вопрос, который будет понятен всем, потом поищите ответ на этот вопрос в поиске, а уж если никак - то задавайте его на профильном форуме, вроде хешкода :) У меня так всегда прокатывает.